# Integrating docusign in aws-amplify application

Tags: docusignapi, aws-amplify

I have an application where the user login is taken care by cognito, i want to integrated docusign such that the user need not login to docusign again, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not about writing an integration per-se, but about user/identity management.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html
and the https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-identity-providers from DocuSign end should give you what you need to set up SSO.
You would need an organization with domain listed etc. to do all of that, but it's doable since using SAML makes it the same for each IDP.

Comment: Thank you for your time Inbar Gazit, i went through the above links, but i think i didn't explain it clear enough, I want to use docusign in my web application in such a way that the user need not login to docusign and i can for example make them sign an NDA when the register for the website.

Comment: Well, if you don't need them to log in at all, you can just JWT. JWT would allow you to use a single master user for all transactions so they can all sign the NDA that is sent from this master user and they don't need to log in themselves.